# how to dismantle a list of objects that is warped with string

Tags: python-2.7

I have got a string which contain a list of objects , I want to "grab out" only the list. I saw you can take off the string with the ast.literal_eval() but it doesn't work with a list that contains objects.

```
class A ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.property = "hello"
objects_lst = [A()]   #original
objects_lst = str(object_lst)
```

I would like to return 'objects_lst' to it's original form.
thanks

Comment: You want to evaluate strings back into Python instances? That sounds like a design problem. I wonder if the use case justifies it?

Comment: I think so, I have to send data through socket, so I have to transform it into a string first, I will be happy to hear any idea.

Comment: Huh. Now I'm glad I asked because that sounds legit to me. Pickle is the first thing that come to mind, though: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in the general case. When Python turns your list into a string, it will call the `repr` method on your instances and include the return value in the string it is building. If you don't write your own `repr` method, Python's default will return something like `"<A object at 0xDEADBEEF>"` (where the hex address I faked is the location in memory Python is using for that object). That string is probably not enough to reconstruct your object, especially not on another system.

There are two reasonable ways to fix this. The first, which will work only for fairly simple objects, is to write a `__repr__` method that returns a string that can be `eval`ed to get an equivalent object back. For your example, that could be `"A()"`, but more often you'll need to include arguments to the constructor (e.g. `"A({}).format(self.property)"` if the value assigned to `self.property` was a parameter to `__init__`).

The other option is to use a better serialization system than calling `str` on your list. Python's `pickle` module is good for most kinds of objects, though it can fail in some complex cases. The `dill` module (which is not in the standard library) extends `pickle` to do even better. If you want human readable serialized output, using `json` or `yaml` might be better. Or, you could write your own serialization logic that handles exactly the cases you care about (and not other stuff). Serialization is a big topic, so if this is an important part of your code, do some research (if it's not that important thing, I'd try `pickle` first and only investigate the other stuff if it doesn't work).

One final thing to point out: Unserializing data you get from an untrusted source may be dangerous. If a hostile client sends an appropriately set up payload, it might be able to run arbitrary code on your system.